# Why do some processes block when my Android phone is connected?

Tags: usb-debugging

I've been trying to reboot (WinXP) all evening, and Emacs (Win32, v23.something, not important) isn't starting... sometimes... it's locked on `mount.exe` (loads up some CygWin things during launch), I finally notice. Can't kill `mount.exe` via ProcessExplorer, either. Killing Emacs kills emacs, and leaves the child process still hanging around, unable to be task-killed.

Running mount.exe manually in a shell gives the same behavior -- the app is just locked up, no CPU activity, but can't kill it.

After several reboots, I realize that my Android Incredible is plugged in for charging (default connection type is "Charge Only"), [the connection is ALSO set to USB debugging].

I unplug the phone... and every instance `mount.exe` suddenly exits (completes what it was doing, I presume).

**UPDATE:** noticed blocking occurring for a few other apps, as well: TortoiseSVN and GoogleTalk, Firefox launch/close; Calibre; FogBugz Screenshot Save-As.

---

The behavior can be replicated by having the phone connected and USB debugging enabled OR disabled, and launching mount.exe in a standard shell. It goes through a couple of drives, then "hangs"

When USB debugging is **toggled**, `mount.exe` will finish (I'm presuming it's a standard exit, as no error messages are thrown).

Using ProcessExplorer I don't see any other apps that are running that appear/disappear with the toggling.

To change the status of USB Debugging: 
`Home >> Menu >> Setting >> Applications >> Development >> [(un)check "USB Debugging"]`

---

`mount.exe` can be replaced above with any of the number of blocking processes.

USB debugging may be on **or** off initially -- it's not one state that blocks; it is EITHER state, and switching to the other state unblocks.

Any pointers, people? Since this is Android related, I put it in here... but it's also PC related ... so... I can see this question getting bounced from every StackExchange forum on *some* technicality.... Cross-posted at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701525/why-does-cygwins-mount-exe-lock-up-when-running-while-my-android-phone-is-conn).

Comment: oh, cool -- this migrated over from gadgets.SE !!!

Comment: Could also be a good question for http://superuser.com/ if it's a PC thing.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the phone to charge only after plugging it in? If not go into settings and there should be an option like "Connet to PC". Click that and change the default setting to charge only. See if that helps. If not power off the phone and computer and disconnect cable. Then power both back up and wait for both to fully boot. Then plug in phone. See if that helps.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear -- "Charge only" is the default type; boot is a red herring - it's the execution of mount.exe that is blocking.

Comment: Yes but you unplug the phone and mount.exe goes away. So that is why I was guessing that your SD card was either improperly mounting or it was mounted at some point and was never properly unmounted. Have you rebooted the phone and computer to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: rebooted each a bunch of times.

Comment: So now my best guess is mount.exe is expecting a drive to mount and isn't presented one so it hangs. It is getting confused. So somehow you need to tell CygWin not to automount (which may not necessarily be the issue) or you need to tell CygWin not to take over devices plugged in. If you plug in other USB devices does CygWin automatically look for drivers/modules and attempt to connect to them? Can you configure it not to do that and test and see if mount.exe still hangs?

Comment: I tried to make it clear that the setting is "charge only" -- there is no mounting of phone volumes involved. see updates that indicate that other processes, non-drive-related, also block.